# How to set Java 7 as default?

Tags: 14.04, java, android, openjdk

For android 4.4.4 development, I needed Java 6. But eventually I moved over to Android 5.0 development which needed Java 7. When I tried using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` and `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`, It succeeds and after the installation completes, I try to set Java 7 as default by using `sudo update-alternatives --config java`. There I see 4 options [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuUAr.png).
I chose the desired option i.e: java-7-openjdk-amd64. And exit.

But at the time of the compilation, it says: that I have java 1.6.x installed. And at that time when I do `java -version`, it says that I'm using 1.6. Then I open a new terminal window and do `java -version` and it says that I have 1.7.x.

How to fix this thing? Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by myself by removing all the java versions and installed 1.7.x again.
Guide which I followed: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218888